# Is voltage same on the surface of conductors? (including not perfect ones)

Tags: conductors

I know that for a perfect(ideal) conductor, it should have equipotential surface.

But does it hold for not perfect(not ideal) coductors?

In other words, is it possible to have more than two points which have different voltages on not perfect ones?

Answer (score 1):

Think of a non-perfect conductor with resistance along its length. In that case, the voltage at any point along the length will by determined by the voltage divider created by the resistors on either side of the point. It's the same as having perfect conductors connecting the source with 2 resistors in series; the voltage at the junction of the resistors is $$E=R_1/(R_1+R2)$$

Now think of the diameter of the wire. If it is connected to the source at the centre of the wire, then only along the centre-line will the voltages be as in the formula above. At the outside of the wire there will be a (tiny) difference, caused by the resistance between the centre and the outside.

So in effect, if you are using non-perfect conductors, every point in or on that conductor is at a different voltage.

Answer (score 0):

As long as a current can run between two positions on or in an object there can be no stationary voltage difference between them.

If a current us driven through an imperfect conductor then of course there is a continuous voltage drop along the direction of the current.